# What does the abbreviation "HTLC" stand for?

Tags: terminology, hash-time-locked-contract

An HTLC is a contract making use of both a hashlock and a timelock. I noticed a discrepancy in what various sources state the abbreviation HTLC is short for. I've found:

- "Hashed Timelock Contract" according to the [Lightning Network Paper](https://lightning.network/lightning-network-paper.pdf)
- "Hashed Time Locked Contract" according to [BOLT #0](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/00-introduction.md#HTLC-Hashed-Time-Locked-Contract)
- "Hash Time Locked Contract" according to the corresponding [Bitcoin Optech topic page](https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/htlc/)

What makes the most sense to be the canonical term? Please add supporting evidence.

Comment: I hate to say it, but given that you've yourself shown evidence of multiple distinct abbreviations being used in fairly high-profile contexts, I think there is no objective answer to that it stands for, and this is an opinion-based question...

Comment: I'm hoping for some bitcoin-inclined linguists to provide their expertise on this matter. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "hashed" makes it sound like the contract itself is hashed. Because the contract *uses* a hash, but is not itself hashed, I would say the H should stand for "hash".

Secondly, because "locked" applies to both the hash and the time components, I'd say it should be a separate word, rather than "timelocked".

Technically, initialisms can omit minor words like conjunctions (there is no standard either way, to the best of my knowledge), so while I haven't seen it used, a sensible meaning could be "Hash and Time Locked Contract." That's my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

> "Hash Time Locked Contract" according to the corresponding Bitcoin Optech topic page

I think term used by Bitcoin Optech is correct.

> Please add supporting evidence

```
===Hash Time-Locked Contracts===

Hashed Timelock Contracts (HTLCs) can be used to create chains of payments which
is required for lightning network payment channels. The scheme requires both
CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY and CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY to enforce HTLC timeouts and
revokation.
```

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/commit/5273cdc3b902022da35b0e673a87efa820270cd1

Comment: Hah, that's funny. The quoted passage is titled "Hash Time-Locked Contracts", and then the first sentence defines "Hashed Timelock Contracts (HTLCs)".

Comment: Right. I missed it. Confused and not sure which one is correct.